# accessing value in map of maps

Tags: c++, pointers, maps, std

```
typedef std::vector<UCHAR> RESPONSE_BUFFER;
typedef TimedHashMap<int, RESPONSE_BUFFER*> TimeResponseHashMap;
```

Inner map prototype has "integer" as key and "pointer to a vector of chars" as mapped value.

```
TimeResponseHashMap* inner_pending_response_map;
```

Outer map is a map of maps. it has "integer" as key and "pointer to inner map" as mapped value.

```
std::map<int, TimeResponseHashMap* > outer_pending_response_map;
```

I insert like this:
Inner map is a userdefined map, hence it has a different format.

```
inner_pending_response_map->Insert((int)s16MessageID, &resp_buffer, expirytime);

outer_pending_response_map.insert(make_pair((int)s16SessionID,       
    inner_pending_response_map));
```

TimeResponseHashMap provides the user defined interface "Find" to access members of the map.

```
template <typename Key, typename ElementObject>
THM_ERROR TimedHashMap<Key, ElementObject>::Find(const Key& k, ElementObject& e)
{

    typename hash_map<Key, BaseElement_*, dw_hash<Key>, dw_equal_to<Key> >::iterator itr;
    try
    {
        itr = h_->find(k);
    } catch ( ... )
    {
        return E_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }

    if ( itr == h_->end() )
    {
        e = NULL;
        return E_ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    e = itr->second->e_;
    return E_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have both the keys and now I need to access the "mapped value" of the inner map. The inner map uses the above Find() function to search. I need to pass RESPONSE_BUFFER variable as the second parameter to the Find() function.

I'm trying to extract like this which gives a wrong output:

```
RESPONSE_BUFFER resp_buffer;
ExtractFragmentResponse(u16Key1, u16Key2, &resp_buffer);
```

Definition of ExtractFragmentResponse is below:

```
STATUS
C_THREAD::ExtractFragmentResponse(USHORT u16SessionID, USHORT u16MessageID, 
RESPONSE_BUFFER* resp)
{
      (((outer_pending_response_map.find(u16SessionID))->second)->Find((int)u16MessageID, resp))
}
```

resp is not giving me correct data.
How can it be done?

Comment: what interface does `TimedHashMap` provide ?

Comment: I have added code for the TimedHashMap interface

Comment: I need to pass "RESPONSE_BUFFER *buff" variable as parameter to ExtractFragmentResponse function.

Comment: @user1124236 One suggestion is to break up the one line into several lines.  Then you should be able to figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: @user1124236 - My suggestion of breaking that line up into several lines may need to be done.  You're assuming that the outer `find` function actually finds something.  `outer_pending_response_map.find(u16SessionID)`  If not, then you're derefencing an invalid iterator when you apply `->second` to this bogus value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not directly answer the question, but it does bring up why the code used is highly faulty and should be broken up into several lines.

```
STATUS
C_THREAD::ExtractFragmentResponse(USHORT u16SessionID, USHORT u16MessageID, 
RESPONSE_BUFFER* resp)
{
  (((outer_pending_response_map.find(u16SessionID))->second)->Find((int)u16MessageID, resp))
}
```

Let's say this did actually "work".  There is a major problem with it, regardless.  The issue is this:

`outer_pending_response_map.find(u16SessionID)`

What happens if `find` doesn't find the entry `u16SessionID`?  You now have been returned `outer_pending_response_map.end()`.  When this return value is used like this:

`outer_pending_response_map.end()->second`

boom, your dead.  That line attempts to use an invalid iterator, which is undefined behavior.

What you should do is this:

```
 std::map<int, TimeResponseHashMap* >::iterator it1 = outer_pending_response_map.find(u16SessionID);
 if ( it1 != outer_pending_response_map.end())
     (it1->second)->Find((int)u16MessageID, resp);
 else
 {
    // you  fill in what happens if the find fails
 }
```

To debug your issue, you can then further break up the lines to ensure what you're getting is valid:

```
 std::map<int, TimeResponseHashMap* >::iterator it1 = outer_pending_response_map.find(u16SessionID);
 if ( it1 != outer_pending_response_map.end())
 {
     TimeResponseHashMap *theMap = it1->second;
     theMap->Find((int)u16MessageID, resp);
 } 
 else
 {
    // you  fill in what happens if the find fails
 }
```

The code above saves `it1->second` to a value (`theMap`) that you can inspect easily to see if it is correct.